# Problem with the build in react js, can't find the build folder

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, serverless

I'm trying to use react, serverless and SSR please don't ask me why I don't use next.js, anyway.

i got the next error ERROR in unable to locate '/home/franklinserif/proyects/ssr-develop/build' glob

here is my server index.js code

```js
// index.js
import serverless from "serverless-http";
import express from "express";
import path from "path";
// import middleware
import renderer from "./middleware/renderer";
const app = express();
// root (/) should always serve our server rendered page
app.use("^/$", renderer);
// serve static assets
console.log(path.join(__dirname, "./client", "./build"));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "./client", "./build")));
// handler
export const handler = serverless(app);
```

and this is my renderer file

```js
// renderer.js
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";
import React from "react";
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";
// import main App component
import App from "../client/src/App";
export default (req, res, next) => {
  // point build index.html
  console.log(path.resolve("../client", "./build", "index.html"));
  const filePath = path.resolve("../client", "./build", "index.html");
  // read in html file
  fs.readFile(filePath, "utf8", (err, htmlData) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.send(err).end();
    }
    // render the app as a string
    const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App />);
    // inject the rendered app into our html and send it
    return res.send(
      // replace default html with rendered html
      htmlData.replace('<div id="root"></div>', `<div id="root">${html}</div>`)
    );
  });
};
```

I don't know why I can find the build folder

Comment: can you check if you indeed have the build folder created at that location?

Comment: i think thats the problem, this is my folder structure, app/all server and webpack server files and serverless files, app/client create react app proyect files